# Is there a way to view total rocket mass in KSP?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I was building a rocket in Kerbal Space Program the other night, when I started to wonder if there was a quick way to view the total mass of a rocket. I was wondering this because each rocket part has a mass value when you hover over it. Of course, I could just add the up the total mass from each of the parts used, but that seems like a lot of work, particularly so considering the the 'throw stuff together' style of rocket building common to KSP.

Is there some easy method for viewing the total mass?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the bottom right of the screen is a set of icons, including a spanner inside a cog. If you hover on that, it will show you a bunch of stats and helpful tips, including the total mass of your ship.  You can use this to help you build something that sneaks in just under the current launch mass limit of your buildings.

There are also a number of mods that can provide insane levels of detail should you want to know more.

[image]

Comment: Added a screenshot for clarity's sake.

Comment: Cheers Tim!  That's a big improvement :)